# Difference between ε-differential privacy and (ε, δ)-differential privacy

Tags: data-privacy, differential-privacy

I don't understand the necessity of introducing the additive term δ in the differential privacy definition. Moreover, reading different papers and blogs they say that because of the δ term the mechanism is "broken" (whatever that means).

I would really appreciate some help in understanding the role and the effect of the δ term.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The $\delta$ item is a **relaxation** of the $\epsilon$-differential privacy notion. The latter is a strong security notion because it requires an algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ to have very close output distributions on "neighbor" datasets $D_1,D_2$ that differ in a single record. From its formal definition

$\Pr[\mathcal{A}(D_1) \in S] \leq e^{\epsilon} \times \Pr[\mathcal{A}(D_2) \in S]$,

we can see that the probability difference should be small for **every** output set $S$ even if the probabilities $\Pr[\mathcal{A}(D_1) \in S]$ and $\Pr[\mathcal{A}(D_2) \in S]$ are negligible. In other words, such a requirement needs to hold for very **unlikely** events. Sometimes we want to relax this definition a little bit to cover more general cases as discussed [here](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2006/40040493/40040493.pdf), so the $\delta$ item is introduced:

$\Pr[\mathcal{A}(D_1) \in S] \leq e^{\epsilon} \times \Pr[\mathcal{A}(D_2) \in S]+\delta$.

This essentially means that those highly unlikely "bad" events happen with probability $\leq\delta$. These "bad" events may break $\epsilon$-differential privacy but are properly bounded.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I understood your explanation, but I still cannot get the concrete advantage of introducing δ. Sure you say an unlikely event in $D_1$ can get more likely to happen in $D_2$. But it could before too, as the sign is $\leq$, which means the probability of an unlikely event in $D_1$ can always be greater in $D_2$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @primef The $\epsilon$-differential privacy definition looks asymmetric but actually symmetric. The condition should hold when you swap $D_1$ and $D_2$ because both $D_1,D_2$ and $D_2,D_1$ are neighbor datasets. The $\delta$ item allows for some bad events that do not fit the strong definition.

Comment: Thanks again, now I understand the reason why $\epsilon$-differential privacy is defined as strong. I also understand that $\delta$ is the **additional** probability for which an event would occur, hence the probability for which the differential privacy guarantee _breaks_. What I'm still missing is the **why**. Why would I want to allow an error in the algorithm, why would I want to (with probability $\delta$) release a query that discloses confidential data?

Comment: @primef One reason for the $\delta$ relaxation is that those bad events happen with very very small probabilities, e.g., smaller than the inverse of any polynomial in the size of the dataset. In practice, such bad events (that can disclose confidential data) do not even happen (with extremely high probability), so we do not need to care about them. This is similar to the fact that cryptography often guarantees security with high probability instead of absolute probability 1.

Comment: I'm sorry to be so insistent, but I still don't get the advantage. The fact that the probability for an error is negligible, is more of a reason why ($\epsilon, \delta$)-differential privacy is not that bad and not a reason why I should switch to it coming from $\epsilon$-differential privacy. What is the benefit of ($\epsilon, \delta$)-differential privacy? You mentioned in your first answer "_to cover more general cases_", could you explain this further? What kind of general cases?

Comment: @primef $(\epsilon,\delta)$-differential privacy is good because it is more general and (as I mentioned) is still considered secure in practice. Then why not make the definition more useful with a $\delta$ relaxation to cover potentially more cases? If you want concrete examples, please refer to [this paper](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2006/40040493/40040493.pdf). Gaussian noise and Binomial noise are better analyzed with the relaxed security notion.

Comment: @primef In case that's still helpful, here is a blog post explaining a very natural scenario in which using (ε,δ)-DP is necessary (or at least, makes things significantly easier): https://desfontain.es/privacy/almost-differential-privacy.html

Comment: @primef I agree with you -- the answers here don't make much sense. It appears as the existence of zero-probability events drive this. In the blog shared by `Ted` you can see an example, e.g., there can always exist a new (unpredicted) category input in histogram queries. Even if such events happen with VERY small prboabilities, they still violate any $\epsilon$-privacy constraint. Hence, you allow an additive variable $\delta$.