# $(\epsilon, \delta)$-differential privacy: main motivation of $\delta$

Tags: data-privacy, differential-privacy

I am wondering **why** (not how) we relax $\epsilon$-differential privacy to $(\epsilon, \delta)$-differential privacy. Is the **main** motivation to reduce the variance of the noise added to the query with a slight sacrifice from the strength of privacy?

Comment: Have you read this answer, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/61200/82720. I think there is trade-off between epsilon and delta.

Comment: @CloudCho thanks! more than the answer, the comments in the link provided addresses to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I help implement and ship anonymization strategies based on differential privacy in a large tech company. In my experience, the $\delta$ is mainly used for two reasons.

- **Partition selection**: when computing histograms on an unbounded space, you can [threshold the results](https://desfontain.es/privacy/almost-differential-privacy.html) (or do [smarter things](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.03684)) and, at the cost of a non-zero $\delta$, avoid having to specify the full list of partitions in advance>.
- **Gaussian noise**: since Gaussian is based on the $L_2$ sensitivity, it is very convenient to use when adding noise to a lot of metrics at once; if a single user can influence $k$ metrics, the noise needs to be scaled by $\sqrt{k}$ instead of $k$ with Laplace noise$^1$. But Gaussian noise doesn't give you pure $\varepsilon$-DP, you have to have a non-zero $\delta$.

Gaussian noise is particularly used for machine learning use cases. In such contexts, you also often want to use results on amplification by sampling, which also require a non-zero $\delta$.